# How do I close an excel workbook using Windows "X" without prompting to save

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro enabled excel file that I use as a master workbook.  All this does is open up a form on workbook load and allows me to choose some options on the form to manipulate a second workbook.  All works fine - I can choose the second workbook, do some actions on it, save it from code behind and close it.  When I am all done I want to close the master workbook but it prompts me to save "master.xlsm".  I do not want it to prompt for this as my users should never save into the master book.  I can only assume excel thinks there were changes because I used the form housed within.

How can I disable the save warning or dispose of the form so excel won't prompt?

Comment: Have you tried `book.close false`?

Comment: you may also need `Application.DisplayAlerts = False `

Comment: @findwindow You win!  Thanks.  That was so simple.  Set it up as an answer and I will mark it as correct if you want.

Also, what does the false parameter pertain to?  Saving the file before close?

Comment: Just remember to turn the alerts back on (`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`)  at the end.

Comment: Glad to help ^_^ Yea, the false tells it not to save.

Comment: @BruceWayne that will be put to true automatically after the macro run (except for cases where critical errors pop up, but then the manual set to true wont also happen)

Comment: You can also open the workbook as readonly so it wont ask to save when exiting.

Comment: @ja72 - Do I just set the file to readonly for this to work?

Comment: @DirkReichel - Ah, I didn't know that, thanks!  Does that also apply to other `Application.` such as `.ScreenUpdating`?

Comment: you need to test it to the limits... sometimes there are problems with vba if the workbook is readonly... (as long as you are only reading values and stuff like that, everything should work without any trouble)

Comment: @BruceWayne yes... for as good as all `application.`-stuff... as long as there no fatal errors (but as said, manual reset will also not happen)... but keep in mind that `Application.Calculate` is a normal setting and wont go back to automatic

Comment: @VinnyGuitara `Workbooks.Open("Book.xls", ReadOnly:=True)`

Comment: @BruceWayne i don't want to spam but: you can do a quickcheck with the direct window -> input something like `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and then put a `?` in front of it (`?Application.ScreenUpdating = False`). if the output is `False` then that setting has an auto-reset

Comment: @DirkReichel - it's not spam, if it's to help!  Yeah, I use that method (like `?Cells(i,1).Value` to double check things.  Cool tip though about checking if it's on auto-reset or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set `<Workbook Object>.Saved = True` before closing it